# Django count queryset:int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, django

I am stuck up with my efforts to count files uploaded by my user
models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class UploadDetail(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views upload function

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.uploaded_by = request.user.profile
            newdoc.save()
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('upload'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the upload page
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    current_up = Document.objects.filter(uploaddetail=id).count()
```

Traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/milenko/mk/malex/views.py" in upload
  47.     current_up = Document.objects.filter(uploaddetail=id).count()

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  836.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  854.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1253.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1277.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1215.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_lookup
  1085.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in __init__
  18.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  115.                 self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "/home/milenko/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  947.         return int(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /upload/
Exception Value: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

This is how migrations file,uploaddetaill looks like

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('malex', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UploadDetail',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('amount', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('document', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='malex.Document')),
                ('profile', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='malex.Profile')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

This is my sqlite dump

```
sqlite> .dump malex_document 
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "malex_document" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "docfile" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "date_uploaded" datetime NOT NULL, "uploaded_by_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "malex_profile" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
INSERT INTO malex_document VALUES(1,'documents/2018/06/25/262_2016-06-16_17-12-37_2016-06-16_17-14-07_R000_131072H.xml','2018-06-25 16:23:25.991626',1);
INSERT INTO malex_document VALUES(2,'documents/2018/06/25/262_V01_C05_R000_TEx_BH_131072H.ats','2018-06-25 16:24:50.293830',1);
INSERT INTO malex_document VALUES(3,'documents/2018/06/25/262_V01_C06_R000_TEy_BH_131072H.ats','2018-06-25 16:26:03.728805',1);
INSERT INTO malex_document VALUES(4,'documents/2018/06/26/262_V01_C08_R000_THy_BH_131072H.ats','2018-06-26 10:43:23.603460',1);
INSERT INTO malex_document VALUES(5,'documents/2018/06/26/262_V01_C07_R000_THx_BH_131072H.ats','2018-06-26 18:55:31.047031',1);
CREATE INDEX "malex_document_uploaded_by_id_456f13bd" ON "malex_document" ("uploaded_by_id");
COMMIT;
```

Django refers to which builtin function?
How to fix this?
What is wrong with my model?

Comment: can you show all traceback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [id](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) is `<built-in function id>`

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    ...
    # here is the wrong line, you pass `id` but you don't have this variable
    # and django take his `id` function
    current_up = Document.objects.filter(uploaddetail=id).count()

    # maybe you need something like this
    current_up = Document.objects.filter(uploaded_by=request.user.profile.id).count()
```

Comment: No,what you suggest does not work.I got name 'uploaded_by' is not defined

Comment: did you have migrations ? you have the `uploaded_by` field in `Document` object, this is your code ?

Comment: do you want yo say that this code `newdoc.uploaded_by = request.user.profile` works, but this code `current_up = Document.objects.filter(uploaded_by=id).count()` don't work ?

Comment: yes,exactly.I used two have two classes but I have added uploaddetail in order to enable upload stats.

Comment: but what is `id` in `upload` function ? maybe `request.user.profile.id` ?

Comment: I would like to know that!

Comment: can you comment out the `current_up = Document.objects.filter(uploaddetail=id).count()` and instead of this put a `print(id)` what do you have ? will the code works, and what would the print give to you

Comment: <built-in function id>

Comment: here is the problem, ca you show your `Document` object where is the `uploadeddetail` field ?

Comment: I can not,I realize that here lies the problem.thanks.

Comment: ok, put the `id` of the object, maybe you need to try something like `request.user.profile.id` i think this will work